# Ionic framework and angular ui calendar issue?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, cordova-3, ionic-framework

I am using ui calendar to provide a calendar view in my application.

**Question:**
 The calendar loads fine and the calendar also accepts events just that I can not seem to access the calendar object using `$scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('prev');` through my controller that i am using.

If I am doing this wrong could you please provide an explanation as to how to access the calendar object?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wF0VZAGDpIhURyVIFUEt?p=preview)

Comment: code example? maybe in CodePen or a similar tool?

Comment: Thanks for responding Aaron, I have put the code into plunker and have taken out the angular ui router, which I suspect is causing the issues, and this allows the $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar object to be accessible in the controllers scope. added a plunker link on question will now try and determine whether or not it is either the anuglar ui router in ionic or something else in the ionic framework

Comment: Any news? I'm facing similar issues

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('prev')
> ```

this essentially invokes a function prev() on the encapsulated calendar object.

```
fullCalendar.js:line 132: var r = calendar[options].apply(calendar, args);
```

After invoking the function it will return `this` which is the result because check this out in fullCalendar.js

```
function prev() {
    renderView(-1);
}
```

This is not returning anything.

If you want to get date try passing 'getDate' to `fullCalendar`

```
 $scope.previousEntries = function(){
    $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('prev');
    var calenderDate = $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('getDate');
  }
```